# Security Questions?

Tags: preinstallation

1. How can I check that Ubuntu is 100% secure?
2. Should I install a firewall, antivirus, malware software, or any other security or are their security software programs installed by default?

Comment: About antivirus check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed

Comment: For the firewall http://askubuntu.com/questions/26736/is-a-firewall-really-necessary-these-days and http://askubuntu.com/questions/22667/why-is-the-firewall-disabled-by-default

Comment: Define 100% secure. The only 100% secure machine is in a locked room, not connected to any networks and _off_. If you are using this for a bank server, you will want to install extra programs. If you are using it to read your mail, the out-of-the-box setup will be fine for you. This cannot be answered unless you explain your requirements.