# does ubuntu 10 04 lts have a built in firewall and antivirus

Tags: security, firewall, antivirus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a preinstalled or automatic firewall?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9206/is-there-a-preinstalled-or-automatic-firewall)
>   [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

I have just installed ubuntu 10 04 lts on my laptop and I am trying to find a firewall and anti-virus suite for it.