# Should I be using a firewall in Ubuntu?

Tags: vpn, firewall, gufw, p2p, firestarter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the firewall disabled by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22667/why-is-the-firewall-disabled-by-default)

I installed both gufw and Firestarter but I'm hesitant to activate one of them because I don't know too much about firewalls in general and I don't want to srew up VPN or P2P.

Comment: Probably not, unless you have a compelling reason to use a firewall.

Comment: similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9206/is-there-a-preinstalled-or-automatic-firewall  or possibly http://askubuntu.com/questions/22667/why-is-the-firewall-disabled-by-default

Comment: Depends on what you use it for. But then again you mention p2p... on a system that needs a firewall I would advice against using p2p anyways. I do think this is a overly broad question that does not really suits AU. Plus if it does it's been asked before :) I like the 2nd one @fossfreedom

Comment: Read the 2nd one. Seems like I don't need one. It's just that people who write articles like "things to do after installing ubuntu" sometimes mention configuring firewalls. So I thought it might be something you ought to do.