# How to prevent certain applications from accessing the internet?

Tags: internet, firewall

I want to prevent certain applications from accessing the internet. When I was using windows XP I had an application (i think it was Zone alarm) which always notified me when an application tried to access the internet. I wonder if there is an application in Ubuntu which would do the same task. If it is possible, please suggest a gui application.

the problem is,
my internet provider allows me to connect to a single host at a time, that means no two applications can use internet at the same time. When i checked system monitor it showing me that internet is working fine still my browser cant browse.So i want to kill the other application using the internet to browse.

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://askubuntu.com/questions/9206/is-there-a-preinstalled-or-automatic-firewall

Comment: Arun, you should edit your post to mention the application. Was it a firewall? I know that firewalls in Windows allow users to control which applications can access the internet.

Comment: For Iphone - Disable the mobile data. Go to Setting, General, and off the Cellular-mobile data

Answer (score 4):

You can use `apparmor`.

> AppArmor ("Application Armor") is a security module for the Linux kernel, which allows the system administrator to associate with each program a security profile that restricts the capabilities of that program.

You can use `deny` statements to prevent applications to access network.
Take a look into [this tutorial](http://www.overclock.net/t/517324/tutorial-secure-ubuntu-with-apparmor) for more information.

Comment: That's an interesting program.